# Overriding equals for Clojure records

Tags: clojure, interop

I have a record where one field is of type `byte[]`. Since Clojure equality is not defined for arrays, we have:

```
(defrecord Record [^bytes field])
(def rec1 (->Record (byte-array (map byte "abc"))))
(def rec2 (->Record (byte-array (map byte "abc"))))

(= rec1 rec2)
; => false
```

This is, of course, not acceptable.

Now, we do have `java.util.Arrays.equals` which defines proper equality for arrays. Since = works so well for other Clojure objects, I don't want to use interop every time I compare my Record type, types including that type etc.

Is it possible to override the equals function for a record to handle arrays as well?

---

I have tried the following:

```
(defrecord Record [^bytes field])
  Object
    (equals [this other] (Arrays/equals this other)))
```

But I get an error, "Duplicate method name&signature".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason arrays don't compare as equal, in clojure, is because they can change at any time, and objects which are equal should stay equal. Imagine a map like `{rec1 1}`. If your two objects compare as equal, I should be able to look up `rec2` in it and find the answer `1`. But if someone does `(aset (:field rec2) 1 3)`, suddenly `rec2` has changed, and is no longer equal to `rec1`!. This is just not something that should happen, so clojure says they're not equal.

This is similar to the equality semantics for atoms and other mutable containers: just because two mutable containers (atoms, *or arrays*) have equal contents now doesn't mean the containers are themselves equal. That tenuous equality could change at any time, when someone modifies one of them. Similarly, your two arrays may become unequal at any time; this means that, really, they were never equal at all.

Comment: Ok, good rationale. In my use case, the arrays never change but I guess I'm still better off choosing another type.

Comment: I decided to use hex-encoded String instead of byte[]. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is there a case for Clojure throwing an exception when asked whether a mutable is equal to something else? Transitory inequality seems almost as bad as transitory equality.

Comment: @Thumbnail the error is when I try to overload .equals, not when I compare. Clojure's way of comparing arrays seems to be just pointer comparison.

Comment: Throwing an exception is appalling. You might just as well say that `(= "x" 5)` should throw an exception: of course strings can't be equal to numbers, why would you ask such a silly question? But no, it's a perfectly fine question, and they're not equal. Likewise, mutable objects are just not equal: there's nothing illegal about asking the question!

Comment: I surrender! If a mutable is identified with its history, or - more so - with its possible histories, it is clearly unequal to another, just as two mathematical functions are unequal even though they have the same value for some arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are mutable and thus not *values*. Clojure equality depends on the immutability of component values in composite things like records. Arrays are dirty mutable things - as a general starting point, just don't do this.

If you really really want to use arrays and you need custom semantics, use a deftype and define your own equals method. But you need to be aware you are then "off the map" as far as Clojure is considered - this is not "normal" Clojure.

Comment: Is this inconsistent with how equality works with ArrayLists? I was just reading another thread regarding hashing on the clojure-dev list which seems to contradict this rationale.

Comment: What's inconsistent? Neither arrays nor ArrayLists are values but concessions are made for both as they come up in performance and interop cases.

Comment: My explanation may not have been clear. If I replace the byte-array in above code with java.util.ArrayList, the equality returns `true`. Hence, the question.

Comment: This is a similarly dangerous thing to do for the same reasons. Clojure is supporting equality for Java collections right now but that may not always be the case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. Was trying to wrap my head around when to and when not to use. Will stay away from it!